# Is it possible to do this pivot in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

Is it possible to turn this dataframe :

```
     A_type  A_1   A_2   
1     a       1     x
1     b       2     y
2     a       3     z
2     b       4     w
3     b       5     u
```

Into this? :

```
     a           b
     A_1   A_2   A_1   A_2   
1     1     x     2     y
2     3     z     4     w
3     NaN   NaN   5     u
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [195]: df.set_index('A_type', append=True).unstack() \
            .swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
Out[195]:
A_type    a          b
        A_1   A_2  A_1 A_2
1       1.0     x  2.0   y
2       3.0     z  4.0   w
3       NaN  None  5.0   u
```

Comment: This approach has one advantage over the `.stack().unstack([1,2])` approach-- it doesn't coerce all the dtypes to object.

Comment: @DSM, thank you! I didn't even think abou it ... :-)

Comment: @DSM cool that is good to know.  Speed is probably not an issue with this operation, but it does appear that `stack().unstack([1,2])` is nearly twice as fast.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use `set_index`, `stack`, `unstack`:

```
df.set_index('A_type', append=True).stack().unstack([1,2])
```

Output:

```
A_type     a         b    
         A_1   A_2 A_1 A_2
1          1     x   2   y
2          3     z   4   w
3       None  None   5   u
```